# How to install Django to IntelliJ in community version?

Tags: django, intellij-idea, module

Hi everyone is there any way to enable or add Django to IntelliJ ?
sadly i can not add Django to module.
with screenshots it will be more easy to understand.
remember one thing that i already installed Django using terminal but still can not see in module

Comment: This probably belongs on another site that handles DevOps questions.  Here we review code and errors.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA Community [has no support for Django](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html). You can use PyCharm Pro or IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for that.

Comment: how about the IntelliJ ultimate version?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate supports Django. It's already in my answer above.

Comment: I asked you ultimate any version?
i asked you about any version of Ultimate?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate available at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html supports Django. Not sure what other versions you are asking about, there could be some language barrier, try to rephrase your question if the answer is still not clear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast feedback.
I meant it does'nt really matter if I want to run any version of ultimate?

Comment: What do you mean by "any version of ultimate"? Django support has been available for a long time, so it should work even with older IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate releases, but some new features may not be present there. Note that you still need to install Python plug-in for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate to get Python and Django support: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#install_plugin_from_repo,

Comment: Thanks again,
believe me since one month that i am trying to fix this issues.
but your help and feedback was really helpful.
Can i send you friend request here? is there any option?
I am new here in StackoverFlow

Comment: No, this site doesn't have friends concept.